# Display full size feature image in mobile version of site

Tags: wordpress, image, mobile, themes, customization

I am using the Xtra WordPress theme. I have set a 1080p quality image as the banner image. The image is displayed correctly on desktop, but it is resized to 768*432 on mobile devices. I would like the image to be displayed in full HD on mobile devices as well. (as an example i want the PS5 pro image to be displayed in full size, i tried a few css code with no luck) thanks in advance.

(also, Unfortunately, I didn’t purchase the theme directly from the theme creators, and their support policy requires verification of purchase for any assistance.)

The page i need help with: https://savisgame.com/13316/ps5-pro-3-features-worth/

The feature image of above link (PS5 Pro), displayed in full size in desktop, but in mobile the 768*432 image replaced and showing, i want the full size image to be shown in all versions.

I tried css code modification, looked at theme settings, header, style.css, theme functions and...